# jbehave writing a story step in multiple lines

Tags: automated-tests, bdd, jbehave

I have a step which is long enough not to be fully visible due to the number of parameters it has. I want it to split in two lines but when I do so the step is not recongnised.

```
When CC payment is made with amount=100 type=VISA name=card-holder-name number=1234567890123456
    verification code=000 expiry month=09 expiry year=14
```

Is there a way to make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I have a lot of parameters in a single step I use a table parameter with the transformer=FROM_LANDSCAPE option, like this:

```
{transformer=FROM_LANDSCAPE}
|amount           |100|
|type             |Visa|
|name             |card-holder-name|
|number           |1234567890123456|
|verification code|000|
|expiry month     |09|
|expiry year      |14|
```

http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/tabular-parameters.html

Another way is to set all your parameters before with the *@Given* annotation